# Android show heads up notification while on a call

Tags: java, android, notifications, heads-up-notifications

I am displaying heads up push notifications from my application. When a push notification comes in while on a phone call, the heads up notification isn't shown but it is in the notification center. What I want is for the heads up notification to be shown while I am talking to someone and stay there until I dismiss it by tapping a Dismiss button I have created on the notification.

Is there a way I can show the heads up notification on the screen even when I'm on a phone call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot influence the behavior of notifications like that. What you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: I was fairly certain there wasn't a way to show the notification while on a call but I wanted to be certain.

Comment: i also have a question regarding heads up notifications.[post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709362/android-heads-up-notification-buttons-not-workiing)